# SignalR push-notification to specific client with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR with MVC4 c# project to send push notification to selected clients only.
For this I am using 'context.Clients.Client' by storing 'Context.ConnectionId' in c# static variable {since unable to use session with signalr}.
But since 'contextConnectionId' is a static variable; the message is still boardcasted to all clients :(

Is there any alternative to session with signal or any other elegant way to do this? (found few related post but no specific answers)

Code as below:

javaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
 {
    var chat = $.connection.PushNotify;
    chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (type, message) {
        if(type == "something")
        {
            alert(message);
        }
    }
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.send($('').val(), $('').val());
    });
 )}
```

In c# HUB

```
[HubName("PushNotify")]
public class PushNotify : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        //assume its c# static variable
        GlobalVariable.contextConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    }
}
public class PushNotification
{
    public void SendMessage(string message, string type = "msg")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GlobalVariable.contextConnectionId))
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PushNotify>();
            context.Clients.Client(GlobalVariable.contextConnectionId).addNewMessageToPage(type, message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can use group.http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Comment: This may be worth a look as well: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you example will work as expected. When you map your connection to your static variable you actually overwrite your static variable to the last connection which called Send method.

> Each client connecting to a hub passes a unique connection id. You can
>   retrieve this value in the Context.ConnectionId property of the hub
>   context.

Which means your `GlobalVariable.contextConnectionId` cannot be a simple string. You have to map your clients in a way, and every client is going to have a unique connection id. Perhaps a dictionary would be enough here, or own class containing more info. (i.e. browser info, IP adderss...)

(Quote is from this link) This should help you: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

**EDIT**

Providing a bit more information:

I believe the simplest solution for your question is to use groups. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Your hub class would contain a method to join a group:

```
public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

And let's say a PostMessage to group which sends to a given group only:

```
public void SendMessage(string groupName, string message, string type = "msg")
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PushNotify>();
    context.Clients.Group(groupName).addNewMessageToPage(type, message);
}
```

When your clients join, they can connect to a group, and everything else will be handled by SignalR.

Joining the group from client and posting message:

```
var chat = $.connection.PushNotify;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.joinGroup("Group1");
    chat.server.sendMessage("Group1", "Hi There");
});
```

Receiving messages is the same

```
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (type, message) {
   ...
}
```

**OTHER SOLUTION**

Another solution could be using your own mapping or the SignalR Connection mapping. These solutions needs to override the OnConnected and OnDisconnected methods and map your connections. i.e.:

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = 
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
    {
        Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
    }
}
```

Like in this example: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#inmemory

Comment: @D Dan: Can u bit illustrate regarding using dictionary in this context.

Comment: About the first (group) version: Where/when the client calls LeaveGroup?

Comment: As an example if I have a map looking for item types (Vehicle, User ... ) these are coming from the feed (SignalR) through their specific groups. If I would filter out i.e. Vehicles on the UI, I might as well leave the Vehicle group updates, since I don't even display them anymore, I don't need up-to-date data, it would be just unneeded traffic.

Comment: Context.User is null why ?